# R- Replace all values in rows of dataframe after first NA by NA

Tags: r, na

I have a dataframe of 3500 observations and 278 variables. For each row going from the first column, I want to replace all values occurring after the first NA by NAs. For instance, I want to go from a dataframe like so:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
 1  3 NA  6  9
 1 NA  4  6 18
 6  7 NA  3  1 
10  1  2 NA  2
```

To something like

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
 1  3 NA NA NA
 1 NA NA NA NA
 6  7 NA NA NA 
10  1  2 NA NA
```

I tried using the following nested for loop, but it  is not terminating:

```
for(i in 2:3500){
 firstna <- min(which(is.na(df[i,])))
 df[i, firstna:278] <- NA
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
# sample data
mat <- matrix(1, 10, 10)
set.seed(231)
mat[sample(100, 7)] <- NA
```

You can use `apply` with `cumsum` and `is.na` to keep track of where NAs need to be placed (i.e. places across the row where the cumulative sum of NAs is greater than 0).  Then, use those locations to assign NAs to the original structure in the appropriate places.

```
mat[t(apply(is.na(mat), 1, cumsum)) > 0 ] <- NA
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [5,]    1    1    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [7,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#[10,]    1    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

Works the fine with data frames.  Using the provided example data:

```
d<-read.table(text="
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
 1  3 NA  6  9
 1 NA  4  6 18
 6  7 NA  3  1 
10  1  2 NA  2 ", header=TRUE)

d[t(apply(is.na(d), 1, cumsum)) > 0 ] <- NA
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  1  3 NA NA NA
#2  1 NA NA NA NA
#3  6  7 NA NA NA
#4 10  1  2 NA NA
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rowCumsums` from `library(matrixStats)`

```
library(matrixStats)
d*NA^rowCumsums(+(is.na(d)))
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  1  3 NA NA NA
#2  1 NA NA NA NA
#3  6  7 NA NA NA
#4 10  1  2 NA NA
```

---

Or a `base R` option is

```
d*NA^do.call(cbind,Reduce(`+`,lapply(d, is.na), accumulate=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this using the `cumany` function from the `dplyr` package, which returns `TRUE` for each element after the condition is met.

```
df <- read.table(text = "X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
                         1  3 NA  6  9
                         1 NA  4  6 18
                         6  7 NA  3  1 
                         10  1  2 NA  2 ",
                 header = T)

library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

na_row_replace <- function(x){
  x[which(cumany(is.na(x)))] <- NA
  return(x)
}

adply(df, 1, na_row_replace)
```